# How to manipulate a specific field in a document (PyMongo)

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

For example, I have a field in my document called "x", which contains a giant string.  I want to be able to read the string word by word.

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client.clients
collection = db.unlabel_review

for post in collection.find():
    documents.append(post)
```

So this returns the entire JSON object list, and calling a certain index on documents will return that document.  What is the syntax to return a field of that document, for example return "id" or field "x" where x holds a string?

Intuitively, I want to say

```
documents[1] -> returns whole JSON object so

documents[1][1] -> returns the first index of that JSON object, but this doesn't seem to work
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,

documents[1]["field name"] will return a specific field.